# If a US president decides to declassify information, is it automatically public?

Tags: united-states, president, classified-information

From:

http://www.politico.com/story/2017/05/15/trump-russia-classified-information-238417

"...While his conduct did not likely break the law — **presidents can declassify information when they choose** ..."

I don't care about the politics of the latest news, but more of the technicality.

If the information is declassified, does/can it become public knowledge?

Can any US citizen compel disclosure declassified information? Can anyone else?

Comment: I think it would depend on what information that's being declassified and if it's a threat to national security.

Comment: But the president can still declassify those, no ?

Comment: this is a question for law.se

Comment: I think a US citizen can *ask* for any information. Whether they get it or not (or how much is redacted) is another question.

Comment: "I don't care about politics" Uhh...you do realize this is [Politics.Stackexchange](https://politics.stackexchange.com/)? This question needs to be moved to [Law.Stackexchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Noah - if disclosure threatens security, then it should stay classified.  If something is declassified, there is no basis for withholding that information.  The designation for something that can't be made public because of its sensitive nature is "classified."  You can't de-classify and then withhold.  If Trump declassified the information, then the public has a right to it.  If he does not want to disclose it, then it stays classified and he divulged classified information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short Answer**

No. Information is not automatically public just because it is declassified.

(Although, in practice, declassified information is often released to the public, because classified information is often declassified for the express purpose of releasing information to the public as a matter of policy.)

**Declassification Does Not Necessarily Imply A Right To Obtain Information**

There are many kinds of information that are not classified, but that are privileged from disclosure by compulsory court process or in a court proceeding, and/or are not subject to the Freedom of Information Act (FOIA). Also, certain committees of Congress and certain officials (e.g. chairman, ranking member) within those committees, have a right to access information that is not available to the general public (subject to a duty to keep secret what has been disclosed to them).

For example, many forms of executive deliberation on policy issues, almost all attorney-client communications, private banking information, private tax returns, many matters related to personnel, and many diplomatic communications are not subject to public disclosure, even if they are not classified documents (a status usually reserved for national security information) and even if they are classified and subsequently declassified.

Of course, there are many kinds of information which are not privileged and not exempt from a FOIA request but for the fact that they are classified for national security purposes (e.g. the address of a formerly classified U.S. military base, or the name of a formerly classified government agency).

If information is declassified and not privileged, but is not subject to a FOIA request, then anyone who obtains it can use it in court or for any other purpose, but may have no way to compel its disclosure absent a lawsuit in which the document would be within the proper scope of a discovery obligation.

**No Liability For A Third Party Tip Recipient**

Generally speaking, once someone with no duty to maintain a secret obtains classified information without breaking the law themselves, they can disclose it to the world without risking any legal sanction for doing so under U.S. law.

**Effect of Disclosure On Classification Status**

On the other hand, if information is classified, even if it is subsequently made available to the general public on the front page of the New York Times, this does not automatically mean that it is declassified. The laws that apply to disclosure of classified information do not have a general exception for classified information that is publicly available.

Sometimes this even makes sense, because classified information that is merely claimed by a media outlet to be authentic is not as valuable to third parties who might want to use it as classified information that is confirmed to be authentic by its governmental authors.

For example, a rumor that there is a CIA station in Windsor, Ontario is not as powerful as an acknowledgement by the U.S. government that this is the case. Until the government confirms the information, it can be dismissed as unreliable or a conspiracy theory.

**Limited Disclosure**

Also, the law does recognize the concept of a limited disclosure of classified information that does not *per se* cause that information to be declassified. Indeed, classified information is routinely shared between intelligence agencies on the basis of just such limited disclosures.

There are also different levels of classification - and a determination that information is not classified at one level does not mean that it ceases to be classified at a lower level. Disclosure to someone with a lower level security clearance than the document revealed, while prohibited, is a different matter than disclosing a classified document to the general public.

Another open question is what remedy is available if the recipient of classified information pursuant to a limited disclosure exceeds the authorized disclosure scope, who is entitled to enforce those remedies, and how those remedies are enforceable (usually cases based entirely on classified information cannot be resolved in civilian courts).